# How to parse uploaded Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, flask

I'm trying to use Pandas to parse an Excel file someone uploaded to a Flask web application but not having much success.

I save the raw stream to a temporary file and then try to read it but pandas complains about the raw byte array:

```
tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
tmpfile.write(request.file['spreadsheet'].read())
sheet = pandas.ExcelFile(tmpfile.name)
```

results in the error:

```
*** XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '\\xd0\\xcf'
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Maybe the file has not been uploaded correctly

Comment: Is there a different Flask API to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: I need to `tmpfile.seek(0)` before being able to read from it.